# Remove lines if included in another file

Tags: bash, scripting, sh

I have a phonebook file (F1) :

```
max;123456
eve;234567
john;443322
```

And list of numbers in file F2:

```
123456
234567
678009
443322
342354
```

I would like to find those numbers in F2, which are not in F1 (678009 and 342354).
What I have found is not what i am looking for. Appreciate any help (code or link).
Thanks, Regards.

Comment: Thanks `konsolebox` for quick answer - works great. I realised that problem was caused by a semicolons at the beginning of all lines in F2 - I don't know why but completely ignored this fact... Thanks for the rest of tips.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{a[$2]++;next}!a[$0]' F1 F2
```

Output:

```
678009
342354
```

Answer (score 0):

One of many approaches:

```
comm  -13 <(cut -f2 -d';' F1| sort -u ) <(sort -u F2)
```

output

```
342354
678009
```